# How to stop Google Calendar from "helpfully" extracting times from event titles?

Tags: google-calendar

When entering an event with the string "1h" at the end (which I do often), Google Calendar "helpfully" decides that I must mean one-o-clock. Like this:

[image]

And so:

[image]

Is there any way to turn off this behavior? I can type "60m" instead, but I'd prefer to avoid that; every character counts on a netbook display!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Google's solution](https://web.archive.org/web/20111203141955/http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=59649) is to put "double quotes" around it - if you enter "Exercise 1h" it will strip the quotes but leave the 1h unmolested, and will make it an "all day" item rather than scheduling it for 1:00 PM.

Comment: Update for 2022: Google now keeps the quotes. Not sure when that changed.